# Salesforce Marketing Cloud Mobile Push Cordova Plugin - Navigate subscriber to a particular screen in the app rather than home screen

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, cordova

We are using Marketing Cloud [Cordova Plugin](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MC-Cordova-Plugin) for sending push messages from Marketing Cloud. When we send the push message, and when I click on the push message it goes on the home screen of the app.

I want to navigate subscriber on a particular screen when clicked on the push message.

I see that in Marketing Cloud SDK there is a [method](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/sdk-implementation/implementation-urlhandling.html), which can handle the URLs but cannot find any documentation for same on Cordova Plugin. Has anyone handled this scenario in Cordova Plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you seek will require you to override notification handling (ref. [Android](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/notifications/customize-notifications.html)) and (ref. [iOS](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/push-notifications/rich-notifications.html)).